# Caching on methods in JpaRepository (Spring Data)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Tools:
Spring-Boot : 1.5.9.RELEASE
Spring-Data-JPA : 1.11.9.RELEASE

Issue:
Currently I have a repository that extended from JpaRepository. In order to avoid frequent DB access, I want to cache some of the CRUD methods in the JpaRepository.
I tried a few ways from what I can find with Mr.Google but non of them working except one.

**EDITED**
 1. Solution mentioned in this [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/master/jpa/example/src/main/java/example/springdata/jpa/caching/CachingUserRepository.java) is workable. However, there is a bad practice (redundancy to me) at here. Imagine if I have 50 repositories extending the JpaRepository, this means that I have to override the save method in 50 repositories.

```
     public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
        @Override
        @CacheEvict("user")
        <S extends User> S save(S entity);

        @Cacheable("user")
        User findByUsername(String username);
     }
```

**EDITED**
 2. Extend the JpaRepository interface. I saw something that might works at [link2](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1198).

In the link, it mentioned 3 different ways to caching the JpaRepository methods. the 1st method is same as what I mentioned in #1. However, I want something similar to 2nd/3rd method so that I **no need to keep repeating overriding the CRUD methods in all repositories**.

Below is some sample code that I have written.

```
    @NoRepositoryBean        
    public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends 
    JpaRepository<T, ID> {

        @CacheEvict
        <S extends User> S save(S entity);

        @Cacheble
        T findOne(ID id);
    }

    @Repository
    @CacheConfig("user")
    public interface UserRepository extends BaseRepository<User, Integer> {
        // when I calling findOne/save method from UserRepository, it should 
        // caching the methods based on the CacheConfig name defined in the 
        // child class.
    }
```

However, it seems like the code (above) ain't working as I getting below exception. I understand the issue mainly happened because there is no name being assigned to the cacheable annotation in the BaseRepository. But I would need to cache the CRUD methods in the BaseRepository that extend from JpaRepository.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No cache could be resolved for 'Builder[public abstract java.util.List com.sdsap.app.repository.BaseRepository.findAll()] caches=[] | key='' | keyGenerator='' | cacheManager='' | cacheResolver='' | condition='' | unless='' | sync='false'' using resolver 'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleCacheResolver@30a9fd0'. At least one cache should be provided per cache operation.

I have been asking Mr.Google for few days and yet can't find any suitable solution. I hope someone can help me at here. Sorry if my question isn't clear or missing something as this is my first time posting at here. Thanks!

Comment: Don't I would say. You are using JPA (assuming Hibernate) and that already has support for caching and will integrate better then Spring Cache in this regard. So just configure your ORM in such a way that the 2nd level caching has been correctly configured and enabled.

Comment: @M.Deinum, yes I'm using Hibernate now. I'm also using Spring Redis as my caching layer. I'm not sure if it will be easy to switch to Hibernate caching. It will be great if you can provide with some documents/links as guidance. Thanks!

Comment: I nowhere said you need to swap your caching I said you should be using the caching integration for your ORM. Not sure if there is a Redis cache provider for hibernate. You can actually configure hibernate to use any JCache implementation and there is one for Redis, so it shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: I saw there are few example about hibernate integration with redis. I will take a look at those articles. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you have required configuration already set up and the stack trace you have posted is the problem. So let's dig it.

There are two problems I see:

1. > j**ava.lang.IllegalStateException: No cache could be resolved, At least one cache should be provided per cache operation**.

   Resolution: Whenever you want to cache the data or evict the data you **MUST** provide the name of the cache, which I don't see provided in your code.

   [@Cacheable's cacheNames or value](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html#cacheNames--) should be defined in order to get the cache working.

   **Example** : `@Cacheable(value = "usersCache")`
2. **The proper cache key**

   Because cache works on `key-value` pair, you should provide a proper cache key. If you don't provide the cache key then, by default, a default key generation strategy that creates a `SimpleKey` that consists of all the parameters with which the method was called.

**Suggestion**: You should provide the cache key manually.

Example :

```
@Cacheable(value = "usersCache", key = "#username")
User findByUsername(String username);
```

**Note: Make sure username is unique because cache key must be unique.**

You can read more [Spring cache annotations: some tips & tricks](https://www.foreach.be/blog/spring-cache-annotations-some-tips-tricks)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I already have all the configuration setup and the application is running fine. I'm just left with the caching issue. I understand that a cacheable annotation must be provided with a name. However, currently I have a baserepository that extends jparepository. I can't put a specific name to the cacheable in baserepository since it will be use by all repositories as a base.

Comment: This answer is completely irrelevant to the question asked. The question basically is how would the spring CrudRepository implementation gets the name of the cache from @CacheConfig annotation defined in UserRepository?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great idea. I ended up trying this and getting it to work.

I created a `BaseRepository`:

```java
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {
    @Cacheable(cacheResolver = "cachingConfig")
    Optional<T> findById(UUID id);
    
    @CachePut(cacheResolver = "cachingConfig", key = "#p0.id")
    // Worth noting - add multiple cache puts if caching by different keys(queries)
    // This gets hard when caching special queries per resource - best I've
    //   found so far is to override this method in resource repositories and add all
    //   the puts/evicts needed
    <S extends T> S save(S entity);
}
```

> Note the `cacheResolve = "cachingConfig"`

Then `CachingConfig` (`CacheResolver`) to resolve your cache exception issue:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@Log4j2
public class CachingConfig implements CacheResolver {
    private final CacheManager cacheManager;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public CachingConfig(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.cacheManager = new ConcurrentMapCacheManager();
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        return cacheManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends Cache> resolveCaches(CacheOperationInvocationContext<?> context) {
        Collection<Cache> caches = new ArrayList<>();

        String cacheName = (context.getTarget() instanceof BaseRepository)
                // When BaseRepository, first interface in list is specific Repository Interface
                ? context.getTarget().getClass().getInterfaces()[0].getSimpleName()
                    // I've standardized around all uppercase domain (UserRepository = USER)
                    .replace("Repository", "").toUpperCase(Locale.ROOT)
                // Fallback to class name (you may have different ideas here)
                : context.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName();

        caches.add(cacheManager.getCache(cacheName));

        return caches;
    }

    // Periodic cache dump - used to see what caches exist and contents when dumped
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 10000)
    public void cacheEvict() {
        cacheManager.getCacheNames().forEach(cacheName -> {
            final Cache         cache       = cacheManager.getCache(cacheName);
            if (log.isTraceEnabled()) {
                Map<String, Object> nativeCache = (Map) cache.getNativeCache();
                nativeCache.forEach((k, v) -> {
                    try {
                        log.trace(String.format("Clearing %s:%s:%s", cacheName, k, objectMapper.writeValueAsString(v)));
                    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                        log.trace("Error", e);
                    }
                });
            }
            Objects.requireNonNull(cache).clear();
        });
    }
}
```

Example repositories:

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends BaseRepository<User, Long> {
}
@Repository
public interface TestRepository extends BaseRepository<Test, Long> {
}
```

Example log statement from the dump:

```
14:06:46.033 [scheduling-1] TRACE CachingConfig - Clearing USER:1:{"id":1,"firstName":"test","lastName":"user"}
14:06:46.033 [scheduling-1] TRACE CachingConfig - Clearing TEST:5:{"id":5,"cool":true}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@CachedResult` on method you want to cache.

In your main class use `@EnableCaching`.

Sample code:
`Main` class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
@RestController
public class SpringBootCacheApplication {

    @Autowired
    SomeBean someBean;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/cached/{key}")
    public int getCachedMethod(@PathVariable("key") String key) {
        System.out.println("Got key as " + key);
        return someBean.someCachedResult(key);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootCacheApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

`SomeBean` class containig method which I wish to cache

```
@Component
public class SomeBean {

    @CacheResult
    public int someCachedResult(String key) {
        System.out.println("Generating random number");
        int num = new Random().nextInt(200);
        return num;
    }

}
```

In the `someCachedResult` method I'm always returning some random value. Since its cached, you'll get random value the first time only.

Here the `SomeBean` should correspond to your `CachingUserRepository` class.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I haven't use CacheResult before. That's interesting. But my main issue is mainly how to cache the basic CRUD methods in a baserepository that extends from jparepository.

Comment: you could implement the `crud` methods you want and just call `super.method` in the implementation? And then put the `@CacheResult` over them.

Comment: I did implement the crud method before. However, when I try to implement them in a BaseRepositoryImpl, the cacheable still can't work (same error - No cache could be resolved). I haven't try with the CacheResult yet but I will give it a try. Thanks for the help!!!